Access Denied for Conversions Api. No way to reapply. Where to go from here?
Im trying to get access to the conversions api, specifically the r_liteprofile scope. I have submitted a form for the conversions api which got rejected with the information
Access was denied for the following reason(s):
Your access request form provided insufficient details to approve your request.
I cant see what was missing in the request form, nor can i reapply. Where the apply button usually is i am presented with "access denied"
I have been through support which redirected me to stackoverflow
I have searched previous questions without luck. And i cant comment on the few which are a bit related as i dont have enough karma.
Has anyone experienced the same and found a way to fix the form or get access to scope i need ?
